# Parse and Viewing Files on WebView

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have some files between the extensions of pdf and doc on parse database
I have a tableview which populates from parse query so when i click on them i want to display the file for that row in a new webview. I'm on final stage now but i could not find a way to get file from parse and view it on webview via Swift.
No issue on code so far my tableview populates and cells are making segue to the new empty webview, of course without file. By the way i'm not sure webview can view the doc files so if it can't please advice me the best way to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to retrieve the URL for the file object, and tell the web view to load that URL. Lets assume you have a `Place` object that has a `PFFile` related to it via an attribute called `brochure`. You can get your `PFFile` object that describes the file (doesn't contain the actual file) with a call like:

`let placeBrochure = myPlace["brochure"] as PFFile`

Then, you'll need to extract the url from that `PFFile`

`let brochureURL = NSURL(string: placeBrochure.url)! // Probably shouldn't force unwrap`

and load it into your webview

`let request = NSURLRequest(URL: brochureURL)
webview.loadRequest(request)`

For your specific case, you'll need to extract the equivalent of the `myPlace` object from some sort of array that represents the data that's used to populate your tableview, and this will probably need to happen in `didSelectRow`.

In terms of support for Microsoft Word .doc format files, it looks like `UIWebView` should be able to handle them: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1630/_index.html