# View Parse PFFile PDF in WebView using Xcode7 and Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiwebview, xcode7

I have an `iOS` project I'm working on using `Xcode7` and `Swift2`.  I have a `PDF` that is saving to `Parse`.  It is saving to a `Parse` `Class` called `IncomingRecipe`.  In this `Class` is a `FileName` column with `type` as a `String`.  It also has a column called `PDFData` and is type `PFFile`.  I want it so when the user clicks on a `TableViewCell` it segues to a new `View Controller` and displays the `PDF` in a `WebView`.

Currently these `fileNames` are in a `TableView`.  I have a segue that goes to the `View Controller` with the `WebView`.  It passes along the name of the `fileName` from the `TableViewCell` as a `Global variable`.

My `query` for the data for the `TableView` code for parse is:

```
var fileName = [String]()
var PDFData = [PFFile]()

var getRecipeQuery = PFQuery(className: "IncomingRecipe")

// Match the query with only items that the current user uploaded
getRecipeQuery.whereKey("userId", equalTo: appUserId)
getRecipeQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

    // Check to see if 'objects' exist
    if let objects = objects {

        for object in objects {

            // An AnyObject that needs to be cast as a String
            var recipeName = object["fileName"] as! String

            self.fileName.append(object["fileName"] as! String)

            self.objectid.append(object["objectid"] as! String)

            self.userId.append(object["userId"] as! String)

            self.PDFData.append(object["PDFData"] as! PFFile)

            self.myFilesTable.reloadData()

        }

    }

}
```

The `TableView` loads the `fileName` as:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "PDFTableViewCell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PDFTableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = fileName[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

I have the code for passing the selected `cell` `fileName` to a `Global variable` as:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "ItemView" {

        let savedRecipedView = segue.destinationViewController as! PDFItemViewController

        if let selectedRecipeCell = sender as? PDFTableViewCell {

            let indexPath = myFilesTable.indexPathForCell(selectedRecipeCell)!

            viewingPDFRecipe = fileName[indexPath.row]

            print("Sending Click: \(viewingPDFRecipe)")

        }

    }

}
```

How can I get the `PFFile` of the `PDA` and display it in the `WebView` on the other `View Controller`?  I can't figure out how to get all of this into a `URL` to be used with the `WebView`.  I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025003/parse-and-viewing-files-on-webview) and tried to implement this with mine, with no success.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't just save the file name with

```
self.fileName.append(object["fileName"] as! String)
```

save the whole list of `PFObject`s. These objects will contain the file name (that you can use for the table view) and the `PFFile` reference (that you can use on drill down). Also, you don't appear to, but you shouldn't pass by global. It just looks like you're passing the file name in the segue.

Instead of passing the file name you should pass the whole `PFObject`. Then, in the destination view controller you can extract the `PFFile` reference and the URL it contains.

Comment: I'm new to this.  How do I pass the whole PFObject?  Do I create a global variable with a type of PFObject and then set it to the current PFObject in the TableView View Controller before it segues to the WebView one?

Comment: I saved the whole list as you suggested.  Please see my edit.

Comment: never global variables! do it exactly the same as the name, just change the variable type

Comment: just save an array of PFObject, you don't need to break it apart

Comment: Did a little tweaking and it worked.  Thank you for the idea behind what I needed to do.